# Не получается изменять значение в state (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Пытаюсь создать корзину покупетеля, при нажатии на кнопку Add to cart, объект добавляется в корзину(state.cart) при повторном нажатии на тот же товар изменяется количество в корзине, не получается при нажатии на кнопки +/-, увеличить/уменьшить количество товаров и их стоимость в корзине, задачу пытался реализовать при помощи setState({}) но не получилось

код здесь:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dutwbu?file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внес исправление в ваш исходник. Вам необходимо изменять массив `cart` каждый раз, когда вы изменяете какой либо объект. Если этого не делать, ссылка на массив останется той же и react не перерендерит разметку.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ijke2u?embed=1&file=index.js